# How to add Tasks Timeline to list view from XML?

Tags: 2013, task-list

I create my own Task list (I want to have some extra fields).

I go to Visual Studio > New item... > List > "Create a customizable list template and a list instance of it:" > Tasks.

When I deploy this list, unlike out-of-the-box task list in Project Site template, this list does not have a timeline in default (AllItems.aspx) view. 
Can I add timeline to a view, and how, from Visual Studio?

Comment: Do you mean a Gantt view?

Comment: No, I mean the timeline, that is above the view. I don't know, maybe it's a webpart, but how can I add it to AllItems ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Making custom lists out of base types in VS creates a new template type. You need to set the Type back to 171 in bot List Template Elements.xml, and List Instance Elements.xml. But my problem is opposite, I would like the base type as 171, because then I also get the new hierachical list where I can indent and outdent tasks. But I would like to remove the Timeline. Anyone?

```
<ListTemplate
    Name="TaskTest"
    Type="171"
    BaseType="0"
    OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
    SecurityBits="11"
    Sequence="360"
    DisplayName="TaskTest"
    Description="My List Definition"
    Image="/_layouts/15/images/ittask.png"/>  

<ListInstance Title="TaskTest"
            OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
            TemplateType="171"
            Url="Lists/TaskTest"
            Description="My List Instance">
```

Comment: Please separate your answer (which is in the right place) and your question (which should be added as a new question and not in the answers section)

Answer (score 0):

Timelines are found on the list folder properties. There we can either remove or add additional timelines. I usually handle this in a way that allows the user to add additional timelines on demand.

A solution is to use JavaScript COM and clone the timeline property. You can also add JavaScript to allow the user to change the default timeline graph or just use the web properties to select the default view. This way you can have a master timeline as well as secondary timelines.

http://www.ozkary.com/2016/06/sharepoint-2013-adding-multiple.html